# How do I prevent concurrentModificationException in my arraylist.sort?

Tags: grails, groovy, concurrentmodification

I am doing a sort of an arrayList. The problem is that the method throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Here's my code:

```
void sortMyLevels(ViewModel myViewModel) {

    myViewModel.myHashMap.values().each {
        it.allLevels.sort { DoubleHelper.parseTilDouble(it.levelPrice) }
    }

}
```

The `Viewmodel` has a map called `myHashMap`.
The values have a list called `allLevels`, that I want to sort based on the `levelPrice`. The method throws a ConcurrentModificationException.

I would be thankful for any help to solve this as I've been trying unsuccessfully myself.

Comment: Could you please add the stacktrace and correlate the line numbers with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the **DoubleHelper.parseTilDouble()** is causing the issue. Its trying to modify the content.
You should first process the map if required and then sort it. Sorting and modification should not be done simultaneously